# Lost the Hard Drive Icon from the Launcher

Tags: launcher, mountpoint

I unlocked the C Drive icon connected to the Launcher. Once I moved it onto the desktop, it disappeared.

In attempting to create an new icon, I was asked to create a mount point.  The mount point  directory then showed 2 links rather than the normal 1. I trolled the web for solutions, but I did not find one that addressed any of the stated issues.

I attempted to find a solution to reconstruct the hard drives that were found during the install and listed in the Launcher but was unsuccessful in doing so.

In summary, I would like to restore the `/media` directory to the original install which listed the drives correctly and have the drive icons appear in the Launcher as they did at the time of the installation of Ubuntu.

I found where all the other icons in the Launcher located in the home Desktop directory but could not find anything that listed the hard drives or the floppy.

Ubuntu 12.10 is installed and all the latest updates have been applied.

Comment: Open a terminal and enter this command: `gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist`  Reboot your computer and tell me the results.